# Notifications are called even if app is running in foreground - iOS12

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios12

After a long testing, I found a very weird behavior.

In a nutshell, the method

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith
     payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

is getting called even if the app is running and in the foreground, but not called for older versions of iOS (same code).

Answer (score 0):

A push registry object manages only high-priority notifications (Like needed by a VoIP app).
PushKit wakes your app whether it was in the foreground or in the background.

Typically, you keep the push registry object running for the duration of your app.

Comment: So review your choice, what is your exact need for the push notifications in your case and consider maybe delivering push notifications using third party services

Comment: But it shouldn't be called if app is already running. Why would it's getting called only on iOS 12?

Comment: Wrong. Although it was introduced to behave for some use cases like VoIP invitations, watchOS complication updates etc.. when app is not running, but it is also is given runtime to process a push.

For the second issue, PushKit works for iOS 8.0+, what iOS version it wasn't working for?

Comment: All iOS versions except iOS12!!